# Reference for a particular case of the classification theorem of covering spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a connected topological space (maybe some other hypothesis should be imposed on $X$). Then I'd like a reference  for the following result:

> The sets:
>    $$A=\{\text{equivalence classes of degree $d$ connected topological coverings of $X$}\}$$
>   $$B=\{\text{conjugacy classes of subgroups $H\subseteq 
> \pi_1(X)$ of index $d$}\}$$
>   are in bijective correspondence.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's a direct application of the general classification theorem, and I'm not sure that proving this is any less difficult than proving the general theorem. Do you know references for the general classification theorem of covering spaces?

Comment: If you have a reference for the usual classification of connected covering spaces of a locally path-connected, semi-locally simply connected case then it will also serve as a reference for this result since a basic fact in covering space theory is that $|\pi_1(X)/H|=|p^{-1}(x)|$ where $p^{-1}(x)$ is the fiber of the covering map $p$ which is classified by $H$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hatcher's algebraic topology book http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Page 67 (theorem 1.38)